# AspectJ: Error can't determine superclass of missing type

Tags: aspectj

I get the error using an aspect in our application.

What do I need to fix this error or what does this say to me?

```
[AppClassLoader@13b8f62] error can't determine superclass of missing type xxx.yyy.zzz.execution.SystemVersion
when weaving type xxx.yyy.zzz.execution.DefaultDServerConfigurator
when weaving classes 
when weaving 
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means that when weaving type `xxx.yyy.zzz.execution.DefaultDServerConfigurator`, the type `xxx.yyy.zzz.execution.SystemVersion` is required, but either SystemVersion or its superclass cannot be loaded because dependencies are missing.

Essentially, the aspects require extra class files/jars that are not on your classpath at runtime.

Comment: Thanks. Actually it's strange behaviour between maven and Eclipse. But your answer help me to find out the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it would have been something like that.  :)

Comment: @Mur Votema, how did you solve your problem with Maven+Eclipse?  I'm seeing the same errors (although using TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader)

Answer (score 9):

Changing the option `cantFindType` to

```
{cantFindType = warning}
```

in the `ajc.properties` file solved the problem to me.

You can specify the property file with `-Xlintfile d:\temp\ajc.properties`

Answer (score 6):

Had the same issue with oracle and kamon-jdbc, adding the following `resources/META-INF/aop.xml` file helped:

```
 <!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">

 <aspectj>
     <weaver options="-Xlint:ignore">
         <include within="oracle.jdbc..*"/>
     </weaver>
 </aspectj>
```

Comment: Thank you! `options="-Xlint:ignore"` made my day!